# What does Kenny say to James?

Tags: analysis, dialogue, faster

In the 2010 movie [*Faster*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1433108/) featuring Dwayne Johnson, there is a scene where he is confronted by a person identified as a Samoan played by Sidney Liufau.  The full scene is here

Can someone tell me what Kenny says and what happens to change James (Dwayne Johnson)'s mood?  He seems to get scared of the tattoo he sees.  What is the significance?

Answer (score 1):

The tattoo was something he had done in prison. Billy Bob Thornton talks a little about it when he refers to it as a "count". It's a count of each gang (not just its members) in prison that tried to take him out. I'm pretty sure Kenny referred to him as a ghost because it's prison slang for someone not affiliated with gangs.

So that's why it was so scary, because seeing it showed that he survived a gang ambush. The more markings, the more gangs he survived.

Comment: I thought he was *Ghost* because he survived being shot in the head and died on the operating table.

Comment: Possible, but I'm not sure if Kenny wouldn't have known that already.  In other words, if he knew The Rock died on the table and was a ghost, wouldn't he have already been afraid of him?  I gotta lean towards the prison slang explanation, because he wouldn't have known until he saw the tattoo.

Comment: But Kenny says, specifically, *"I know who you are."*...so it seems reasonable that he would know Driver's story. Kenny knows what the tattoo means so he's pretty well informed...

Comment: Yeah, good point.  I don't know, it could be that the prison slang reference was unintentional.  It's kinda hazy and there isn't any explanation so I guess that part is up in the air.  Either way, he definitely recognizes the tattoo as a count, and that's what spooks him first.  How he doesn't recognize Driver when he first walks in the door is beyond me; he's kinda hard to miss.

Comment: I was also under the impression that when the term 'ghost' was used that it was a supernatural reference.  Kenny did not seem to be the kind of person to be afraid of a guy because he fought off gang members.

Comment: So you think Kenny didn't recognize Driver, looked at Driver's tattoo, and then got spooked just because he remembered Driver got shot and lived?

Comment: Looking up "prison slang ghost" resolves into many hits saying not registered into the prison. A particularly hard to deal with prisoner may be 'ghosted' from prison to prison, so that (e.g. lawyers, rights orgs, etc) cannot locate them and they can be treated (or mistreated) with little or no ramifications.